# How to assign a memory address to a variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables, pointers

here's the scenario:

I foolishly forget to assign the returned object to a variable:

```
>>> open("random_file.txt")
<open file 'random_file.txt', mode 'r' at 0x158f780>
```

Is there a way to directly assign the memory address to a variable? Something roughly equivalent to

```
int *ptr;
*ptr = 0x158f780;
```

Counter-points:

1. In this case I can just discard the object - the file's opened in read mode and the object will be collected by the GC. But I'm interested in a solution for the scenario where I need to free the resource in a deterministic way.
2. I assume that the "at 0x158f780" part is just the id() of the object - which happens to be the memory address in CPython ("this is implementation-specific and may change, blah-blah"). So I'm interested in both scenarios - binding a variable to the id() value would be great (more portable and what not), but binding it to a bare memory address would also be O.K.
3. I did google around a bit for anything "python pointer"-related, variable/memory address assignment and similar, but it seems my google-fu is not strong enough.

Cheers,

**EDIT:**

Some tangents after reading the answers and browsing the python docs: the file object is referenced by the REPL _ var. As soon as _ is assigned to the result of the next command, I assume its refcount goes to 0. The file object is removed from memory, and if we assume it implements a sane `__del__` method, it should take care of all the low-level details, i.e. closing the file and so on. http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__ details the general scenario.

That and I'll be adding 0.0.0.0 stackoverflow.com to /etc/hosts...

Comment: Though not directly what you ask for, in the python interpreter you can get the return value of the previous line from the `_` variable, so `ptr = _` would give you what you want -- the open file object.

Comment: There are *very* few issues that are not worth caring about. Even the decision to not care about them requires thought. Simply ignoring things is usually a bad thing to do.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim: "There are very few issues that are not worth caring about"  While true, this is clearly one of the few issues that so transcends the rules as to be a poster child for things that reach a staggering depth of irrelevance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python is a high level language. You can't (not directly anyway) mess with memory addresses so the answer is no.

The REPL however does conveniently store the result of the last expression in a magic variable `_`. You can fetch it from there. To quote your example.

```
>>> open("/etc/passwd","r") #Oops I forgot to assign it
<open file '/etc/passwd', mode 'r' at 0x7f12c58fbdb0>
>>> f = _ # Not to worry. It's stored as _
>>> f
<open file '/etc/passwd', mode 'r' at 0x7f12c58fbdb0>
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't, for the same reason you can't allocate and free memory yourself and can't cast (as in "let's reinterpret this chunk of memory as if it looked like this") things: Dealing with memory on this level is deemed to error-prone, unimportant and automatable to be included in the language. Be glad it's that way, you propably would have eperienced a few crashes and subtle bugs by now caused by fools who though they'd be clever and abuse something along these lines.

As others have states, the last object printed is stored in `_` by the REPL, so you can use that if it happens during an interactive session and you catch it soon enough.

(Note that strictly speaking, you could write a CPython extension that provides a function to take a Python int, take raw unboxed value and cast it to a `PyObject *`. Both awful and impractical.)

Comment: Completely agree on the manual memory management bit. Thank god I didn't have to work on anything big enough to matter back in the C days. Oh well, there's always the story of Mel for those faux-nostalgia pangs.

Comment: FWIW, I did have to write C extension that would cast an area of memory as a structure that would be filled in with C equivalents of Python data. This could be passed into an IOCTL to get some low level stuff done. It's not always done but possible and sometimes necessary.

Comment: Casting is done in at least one major Python module: NumPy, which allows users to perform low-level casting on arrays.

Comment: @EOL: If you refer to the `cast[]()` function, that's not the cast I was talking about, that's what is also described as conversion. Doing it the other way (taking a chunk of memory filled with int values, then just go and treat it as if it way filled with floats) leads to completely meaningless values.

Comment: @delnan: I was referring `a = numpy.array(range(8))`, which creates an array of 8 `int32` integers, but that you can transform into an array of 32 bytes with `a.dtype = 'int8'`.  In effet, NumPy lets you see the underlying memory in different ways.

Comment: @EOL: That actually works? In that case, I stand corrected. Although I doubt it's considered a good idea in general, or very useful with floats.