# Python - when one integer variable is changed, make the second variable the same

Tags: python

I have two **integers** `x` and `y` that are equal to each other. Whenever I change `x` I want the change to also be reflected in `y`. How can I do that with Python?

I think this can be achieved somehow by pointing both variables to the 'memory location' where the value is stored.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger function on value change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190468/how-to-trigger-function-on-value-change)

Comment: What is the data type? For mutable objects such as lists, you are already there. For immutable types such as integers and strings, you'll need a container.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: I think this is, ironically, an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can't assign a variable to a memory location and you can't retrieve an object at a memory location. You can't use "pointers" as you might in C. I think you're going to have to explain *why* you need these variables to be equal and "where" they exist relative to each other.

Answer (score 1):

lists and dictionaries act as pointers in python so a hacky version of what you're attempting might look like this:

```
In [16]: x = y = [0]

In [17]: x
Out[17]: [0]

In [18]: y
Out[18]: [0]

In [19]: x[0] = 10

In [20]: y
Out[20]: [10]

In [21]: x
Out[21]: [10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate both in a function or such ... read/write is controlled through the function thus assuring the behavior you require

Answer (score 0):

From [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pointers_and_references#Python):

> Python does not have pointers and all Python names (variables) are implicitly references to objects. Python is a late-binding dynamic language in which "variables" are untyped bindings to objects. (Thus Pythonistas prefer the term name instead of "variable" and the term bind in lieu of "assign").

From what I can infer, when working with integers, you can't point `y` to `x` and do something to `x` and see the changes happen to `y` as well.

At the very best, you can change `x` and `y` simultaneously, in 2 ways:

1. Multiple assignments (bindings)

   ```
   >>> x = y = 9
   >>> print (x, y)
   (9, 9)
   >>> x = 6  # won't change y
   >>> print (x, y)
   (6, 9)
   ```
2. Tuple unpacking

   ```
   >>> x, y = [9] * 2
   >>> x, y = (9, ) * 2  # alternative
   >>> print (x, y)
   (9, 9)
   >>> x = 6  # y says "nice try, x"
   >>> print (x, y)
   (6, 9)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

[You can't.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830179/how-to-assign-a-memory-address-to-a-variable-in-python)

You're going to have to figure out another way to keep track of things. I think you probably could be structuring your code to use a **mutable** data type, like a `list` or `dict`, or perhaps create a custom one:

```
class MutableInt:
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self._value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        self._value += other

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._value)

mutable_int = MutableInt(4)
print(mutable_int) # 4

def addOne(mutable_int):
    mutable_int += 1

addOne(mutable_int)
print(mutable_int) # 5
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change the `x` or `y` via a function, try the following code:

```
def change_x(value):
    global y
    y = value
    return value

def change_y(value):
    global x
    x = value
    return value

x = y = 3
print(x,y)
x = change_x(5)
print(x,y)
y = change_y(6)
print(x,y)
```

Comment: In general, the use of `global` is less-than-ideal. It would be better to fix a bad structure than to try to work around it with `global`.